# How to update content of an existing Azure blob with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to update/overwrite the contents of a simple azure blob that holds a txt file with simple a date string inside. I am using it as a way to store the last run time of a certain process.

I have tried a few methods and had no luck also struggling to find any documentation that will help my cause. Any help or recommendations are appreciated.

```
import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient

maxdate = datetime.datetime.now()
now = maxdate.strftime("%m-%d-%YT%H:%M:%S")

def upload_to_blob(data):

  conn_str = "<conn_str>"
  blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)

  blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="vstscontainerreleases", blob="last_run.txt")

  blob_client.upload_blob(data)

upload_to_blob(now)
```

I have tried the above simple reuploading the same blob but get an error saying blob already exists.

```
Time:2021-08-18T11:53:00.0692411Z
ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists
Error:None
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written and any errors you’re getting.

Comment: its not to do with errors im asking for helpful resources that will help me into finding a solution I am asking if anyone knows where I can find helpful info on updating/overwiting the contents of an exisiting azure blob

Comment: You simply reupload the blob. It will overwrite the contents. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: tried that and added code and error for reference still an issue with the blob already existing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

to

```
blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

and that should work.